# Highcharts format labels on grouped stacked bar diagram with $ k, M for currency and 'hrs' for time

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). I have a grouped stacked bar chart that contains revenue and hours as the two series, with billed / not billed as the stacked series. I want to show the labels on the bars for hours abbreviated to `K / M` and the same for currency bars (but with '$' in front of the number).

I managed to do this on both y Axis but I have not been able to achieve this on the labels over each bar (and the totals labels at the top) as well as the tooltip.

The finished product should:

1. RHS yAxis with `k` for thousands and `M` for millions. Right now it starts with `k` and stays like this. I want `k` for the thousands and `M` as it steps into million values. I want the `$` in front (like it is).
2. LHS axis looks OK now but it has the same problem if the data reaches 1 million or more. It should work like point 1 without the `$` symbol.
3. The labels on each bar should format in the same way as their respective y Axis (`$` and `k` and `M` for revenue and just the `k` and `M`, but with one decimal place for hours).
4. The tooltips should also format like the labels in point 3.

Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/uy81h3os/) showing the chart. I cannot seem to find an example of this. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question. I've worked up a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/uy81h3os/3/) that addresses most of your questions, as well as some suggestions I hope you find helpful.

First, for your axes labels, you can use the `formatter` attribute within `labels` in each of the axes to define how you want to show them. For your revenue, I included the prefix "$"; I didn't include one for hours.

I used the `Highcharts.numberFormat()` function in the `formatter` for each axis. This will add a thousands separator (comma) to your numbers and fix the decimal points (the second parameter in that function). For hours, you had fractions of hours, so I set the number of decimals to show at 1. For revenue, I fixed the number of decimals to show at 0. Feel free to change these as you see fit.

As for the K/M labels, I would strongly suggest fixing the values in thousands and stating such in the axes titles (for example, "Revenue (in thousands)"). This is what is typically done in economic and financial charts, and will make the labels clear and consistent for your users. See my changes to your axes title text attributes.

Here's the complete code for the y-axes:

```
yAxis: [{
  title: {
    text: 'Hours (in thousands)'
  },
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value/1000,0) 
    }
  },
  reversedStacks: false,
  stackLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.total,1) 
    }
  },
}, {
  title: {
    text: 'Revenue (in thousands)'
  },
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value/1000,0) 
    }
  },
  stackLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
      return '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.total,0) 
    }
  },
  opposite: true,
  reversedStacks: false
}],
```

I made one other change to your fiddle that you'll see at the top. This adds a thousands separator for all of your numbers, so they show up at `10,000` rather than `10 000`, as you had before. Here is the code:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: { thousandsSep: "," }
});
```

This a global function, so you'll want to place this directly before your chart code.

I'll do some research on your tooltip formatting and edit this answer with further details.

[image]